# Performing viewshed analysis using QGIS

Tags: qgis, viewshed, planning

I am trying to find what points (buildings) along a coastline are directly visible from a specific stretch of beach.

I have various digital elevation and surface models available and vectors for the lots/building heights that are my observer points and I am able to run viewsheds to create rasters with their field of view no problem. Another bit of complexity is the points represent future development, so I'm trying to find out whether new development built to the maximum legal height will have an impact on the beach, and there are multiple rows of potential buildings.

However, how do I select the observer points that directly view the beach after I have created the viewshed (I have a polygon vector for the beach) and remove any observer points that don't?

From my understanding all the viewshed does is show how many observers see a certain pixel, it doesn't specify which observers.

Is there any way to glean this information?

The end goal is to create an overlay/polygon layer for building zoning conditions. So if a proposed building is going on a lot that is viewable from the beach it must have special conditions etc.

I may be able to do it with trial and error, running a new viewshed every time I remove an observer point, but there are hundreds of points and it's not really feasible or accurate.

I have also considered running the viewshed from the beach but as I'm working with proposed buildings there becomes an issue where if I create hypothetical buildings on the front lots for the viewshed to see or not, they block sight of any potential buildings behind them. so it's not overly helpful.

I'm starting to think that maybe I need to tackle this from a totally different plugin than viewshed.

I just found this on ArcMap that does exactly what I need, is there anything similar on QGIS?

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/observer-points.htm